# gce nginix-ingress type NodePort and port:80 connection refused

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-compute-engine

In my gce kube-cluster, i'm using nginx ingress controller instead of google load balancer, by using "nginx-ingress" with NodePort instead of type LoadBalance as below:

```
helm install --name my-lb stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.service.type=NodePort
```

Since nginx-controller deployed as "conroller.service.type=NodePort", the nodePorts were opened/assigned(kubect get svc), also got external ip 104.196.xxx.xxx.
At this point nginx-ingress-controller is running in kube-cluster and confirmed in console "networking/load balancing" that no cloud load balancer created.

```
kubectl get svc
NAME                                  CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
my-lb-nginx-ingress-controller        10.39.249.242   <nodes>       80:31181/TCP,443:31462/TCP   15h
my-lb-nginx-ingress-default-backend   10.39.246.94    <none>        80/TCP                       15h
```

After this, created a new firewall rule in console "networking/firewall" to allow node ports "tcp:31181;tcp:31462".
Now using browser/curl to reach "http://104.196.xxx.xxx:31181" or "https://104.196.xxx.xxx:31462" gets response from ngnix controllers..works well.

But, port access through port 80 not working. When I do curl on "http://104.196.xxx.xxx:80", get back connection refused as below:

```
* connect to 104.196.xxx.xxx port 80 failed: Connection refused
```

Note, 
firewall rules have "default-allow-http" for "tcp:80"
ngnix-ingress version = nginx-ingress-0.8.5
kube-server-version = Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.5"

```
helm ls
NAME        REVISION    UPDATED                     STATUS      CHART               NAMESPACE
my-lb       1           Fri Sep 22 23:05:30 2017    DEPLOYED    nginx-ingress-0.8.5 default  


kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"5", GitVersion:"v1.5.2", GitCommit:"08e099554f3c31f6e6f07b448ab3ed78d0520507", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-01-12T04:57:25Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.5", GitCommit:"17d7182a7ccbb167074be7a87f0a68bd00d58d97", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-08-31T08:56:23Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Any idea why "https://104.196.xxx.xxx:80" gets "port 80: Connection refused" while "https://104.196.xxx.xxx:31462" is working fine?

Thx.

Comment: im currenly havin same issue exactly. could you find a work-around or sth ?

Answer (score 0):

When using a `NodePort`, as is very clearly described in the [NodePort documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport), it translates the `Service` port number to a random(+/-) port in the high 30,000 range which that `Service` will use on the Node itself.

Think of it in that if `Service` `alpha` wants to listen on port 80, and `Service` `beta` wants to listen on port 80, without that translation mechanism `alpha` and `beta` could not exist in the cluster at the same time. Those two ports (31181 for 80, 31462 for 443) are assigned to the `Service` -- nothing else in the cluster will listen on those ports for as long as that `Service` is declared.